# Error reloading Apache with systemctl

Tags: apache2

Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7

I just recently removed PHP 5.6 and upgraded to PHP 7.2 on my system. At the same time I updated all packages and now I am getting an error when I try to reload Apache. This used to work fine before.

Output of `sudo systemctl reload apache2`:

> Failed to issue method call: Unit apache2.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status
>   apache2.service' for details.`

Output of `sudo systemctl status apache2`:

> apache2.service
>      Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
>      Active: inactive (dead)

In `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I can see:

> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16005] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

I have tried removing and re-installing `apache2` but still having this problem. Any other way I can debug this problem?

Comment: What happens if you **restart** the service? `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
Perhaps you can disable some sites and test if apache can restart `sudo a2dissite ...`

Comment: i'm having the same issue...